# Why a .pth file is created sometime on package installation?

Tags: python, setuptools

Sometime, when I install a package, I can notice that a .pth file has been created in the site-packages dir just at the same level as the package code. For example, if I do a

```
pip install DjangoDevKit
```

I can see in site-packages directory :

```
djangodevkit                        (a directory)
DjangoDevKit-1.0.7.dist-info        (a directory)
DjangoDevKit-1.0.7-py3.5-nspkg.pth
```

The .pth file contains:

```
import sys, types, os;p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('djangodevkit',));ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py'));m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('djangodevkit', types.ModuleType('djangodevkit'));mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]);(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

How this `DjangoDevKit-1.0.7-py3.5-nspkg.pth` has been created ? 
The setup.py does not tell to create such a .pth file. I searched into the code but there is nothing obvious.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DjangoDevKit is [a namespace package](https://github.com/bearstech/DjangoDevKit/blob/40b8a220b3072a5153126905fa821daf27e367e6/setup.py#L59). That's why `setuptools` created [`*_nspkg.pth`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/b62705a84ab599a2feff059ececd33800f364555/setuptools/namespaces.py#L13).

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+namespace+package

Comment: Do you know why the creation of the `.pkg` file persists even after [the commit described here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/805)?

Comment: @MikeC What version of `setuptools`? Do you use [PEP-420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/#specification)-style implicit namespace packages?

Comment: It's setuptools 59.6.0, the most recent that would install into Python 3.6.9. (I know, that version of Python is no longer supported; we are planning an upgrade soon but I can't make that jump yet.) pip 21.3.1, if that makes a difference. And yes, we're using an implicit (PEP420) namespace. (and of course, I meant the `.pth` file, not `.pkg`.) There is also an `easy_install.pth` that gets created.

Comment: @MikeC Then sorry, I'm out of ideas. I use namespace packages [very sparingly](https://pypi.org/search/?q=m-lib), and I use old style. My primary Python is 2.7.

Comment: I discovered the issue: I had a `namespace_packages` entry in `setup.cfg`. Removing that allowed install to proceed without. However, there is still also an `easy_install.pth` created; I'm not sure whether this can be avoided at this time.